# Calling Differences Between Actor Components and Character Classes

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

We are currently implementing TraceinActorComponent and calling it into the Character class. However, HitResult is not returned properly and other functions are not working. What is the cause? I set Mesh collision to OverlapAll and turned on SimulationGenerates.

this is My cpp code ::

Character class :

```
AFPSCharacter::AFPSCharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    ActorComponent= CreateDefaultSubobject<UActorComponent>("ActorComponent");
    ActorComponent->Parent = this;
}

void AFPSCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    Movement();

    AActor* traceActor;
    traceActor = ActorComponent->Trace();
    if (traceActor)
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 1, FColor::Yellow, traceActor->GetName(), true);
    }
}
```

ActorComponent class :

```
AActor* UFPSCharacterGunComponent::Trace()
{
    bool isHit;
    FHitResult Hit;
    FVector Start, End;
    FCollisionQueryParams Params;

    Start = Parent->GetActorLocation();
    End = Parent->GetActorLocation() + Parent->GetActorForwardVector() * Range;

    isHit = Parent->GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByObjectType(
        Hit, Start, End, ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility, Params
    );

    {
        FColor Color = isHit ? FColor::Red : FColor::Green;
        const float lifeTime = 1.f;
        DrawDebugLine(Parent->GetWorld(), Start, End, Color, false, lifeTime, 0, 5);
    }

    if (isHit)
    {
        HitActor = Cast<AActor>(Hit.GetActor());
        if (HitActor != nullptr)
        {
            return HitActor;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```